# Is it possible to summon a Minecraft item with a custom amount of usage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a map in Minecraft, and I want to have a really OP bow, however, I want it to only have about 5 or 10 uses. I know how to use the `/give` command to give custom items to a player. I want the item to be a bow with Power 4 and Punch 7, but with only about 5 uses. I know how to do the power 4 and punch 7 part by using the command `/give @p bow 1 0 {ench:{[id:48,lvl:4],[id:49,lvl:7]}}`. 
Is there a tag that allows you to set how many uses the item has?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I give myself a damaged item on 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338339/how-can-i-give-myself-a-damaged-item-on-1-13) (closing older question as duplicate of newer one because this question has an outdated answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/give @p bow 1 380
```

Will give you a bow with 5/6 durability remaining (Forget how Minecraft handles durability internally.) Combines with your enchantments, you get:

```
/give @p bow 1 380 {ench:{[id:48,lvl:4],[id:49,lvl:7]}}
```