# How can I give myself a damaged item on 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't understand how the json code works in Minecraft, so I'm wondering how can I give myself a "damaged" item using commands?

I tried to use the old 1.12.2 way where you would just add the damage, like

```
/give @s minecraft:elytra 1 50
```

with 50 being damage, but it no longer functions correctly, and fails to parse in 1.13 and 1.13.1

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, write your command in with the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/give` command in Minecraft 1.13 has been changed to this format:

```
give <player>[<selectors>] <item>[<NBT>] [<count>]
```

Knowing the NBT tag for damage being `Damage`, I wrote this command. (*Don't currently have minecraft installed to test it, but it should work.*)

```
/give @p minecraft:elytra{Damage:50} 1
```

[This page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give) on the `/give` command and [this one](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure) showing what tags you can apply to items should be helpful in understanding how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

This one command is the updated one for 1.13+
(/give @p minecraft:elytra{Damage:500} 1)

500 being the damaged one.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, this question already had your exact answer as the accepted, try to bring something new to a question when you bring a new answer.