# How do I create tools that can break only certain blocks and has a certain durability in minecraft 1.13.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used this command: `/give @p minecraft:iron_hoe{CanDestroy:["grass_block"]} 1 250`, but it won't give the hoe with the certain durability. How do I make this work in 1.13.2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An item to break only SPECIFIED blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246297/an-item-to-break-only-specified-blocks) and [How can I give myself a damaged item on 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/338339/185203)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Actually just try `/give @p minecraft:iron_hoe{CanDestroy:["grass_block"]} 1` and then just use it yourself to wear out durability, or if you don't like that you can try `/give @p minecraft:iron_hoe{CanDestroy:["grass_block"]} 1 250` again.

Comment: **ok** _lets hope this works_ `ok`

Comment: i used the command and then made a machine to us an item up.

Answer (score 2):

the actual command you're looking for is the following;

```
give @p iron_hoe{CanDestroy:["grass_block"],Damage:<value>}
```

for `<value>`, place the amount of damage you want to have on it. if you have a specific durability value in mind, subtract that from the max durability the item has to start.

Answer (score -3):

try:

> /give @p 1 250 minecraft:iron_hoe{CanDestroy:["grass_block"]}

kbai

Comment: it does not work