# How to create a damaged item in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need an item to have one durability and only break one block, so I need this command:

```
/give @p minecraft:wooden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:dark_oak_planks"]} 1
```

to also spawn it with only one durability but I don't know how, thanks for your help (also I'm in 1.17.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I give myself a damaged item on 1.13?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338339/how-can-i-give-myself-a-damaged-item-on-1-13)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/give @p wooden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:dark_oak_planks"],Damage:58} 1
```

Note the number in bold, that states **how much a tool has been used before**. So if you want to change the wooden axe to a, let say iron axe, and iron axe has a default durability of 250, so you would write:

```
/give @p wooden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:dark_oak_planks"],Damage:249} 1
```

The reason it is 249 is because it is one less than the default durability, which is 250.

Comment: I tried this and it just said invalid because it thinks I'm trying to give the count, and i typed it exactly as you did, i tried it both normally and in a command block, and it just states the 58 part as invalid

Comment: Let me check it again, give me a second.

Comment: @B1M0 It should work now, try it.

Comment: thank you so much for the help it works now

Comment: @B1M0 Do you mind if you can click the check mark next to my answer? It would be most helpful.